# What's an efficient way of synchronizing git pull requests and restarting systemctl services for multiple Django-Q clusters?

Tags: django, git, synchronization, distributed-computing, django-q

I'm running numerous [Django-Q](https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) clusters (on Ubuntu focal) to perform distributed computing on large data sets. I have production clusters and development clusters that each have their own git branch. I need a way to synchronize the updating and restarting of these cluster systemctl services when changes to their respective git repositories are made.

Currently I ssh into each machine and run the following commands.

```
$ git pull
$ sudo systemctl restart qcluster
```

I appreciate any ideas you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this resides in its on-demand aspect.
You need to detect somehow there are new commits, and then initiate your SSH+pull+restart.

Depending on your remote hosting service (GitHub/GitLab,...), you would set a [webhook](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/about-webhooks) listener on each reachable, to automate that step.
Once the listener receive notice of a new commit, it can in turn connect to the clusters and operate your commands.
An [Ansible playbook](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/automation/what-is-an-ansible-playbook) would be a good fit, since [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) is agentless, and relies mainly on SSH to execute scripts on remote machines.

Comment: Thanks @VonC ! I am using Azure DevOps. I'll check out webhooks and Ansible.

Comment: @JonHebert Did you find an adequate playbook, in your Azure context? If yes, don't hesitate to post an answer here: that will help others.

Comment: I have not implemented yet. As soon as I get a couple hours, I will take a crack at it and post what I end up doing.